# Uipath legacy Google suite activities not compatible with Windows type project

Tags: google-workspace, uipath, rpa, uipath-studio, uipath-activity

Is there a way to come-up with packages to reuse google suite activities from legacy project to the windows type projects? Working with google sheet activities and they are working in the windows legacy project but not able to reuse them in windows type projects.

Comment: If not ported to Windows type, nope, this will not work. You can only search for alternatives or create the library on your own.